# What does a-z-A-Z mean in a regular expression?

Tags: regex, go

I've been working with someone else's code and I ran across the regular expression `[^0-9a-z-A-Z]`. This bears close resemblance to the common `[^0-9a-zA-Z]` which is meant to exclude non-alphanumeric characters, but note the extra dash in the middle, between the lowercase `z` and uppercase `A`.

I'm not very familiar with regular expressions, but I've read several pages on them now, and none of the rules I've seen seem to cover what this syntax would mean. Perhaps it's not even valid syntax, but the Golang regex interpreter doesn't seem to mind. I'd appreciate any clarification. Thanks.

Comment: Whose upvoting this? Fess up! There is no behaviour I can think of that is sensible where this doesn't mean "literal dash" - Does the OP have any hypothesis at all?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

A dash in a character class in a place where it cannot be interpreted as a range is interpreted as a literal dash. So the expression excludes the characters `0` to `9`, `a` to `z`, `A` to `Z`, and `-`. That's why there's no syntax error.

It's probably a typo though. If the dash is meant to be there, then to prevent confusion it should be escaped and/or moved out from between the ranges, such as `[^0-9a-zA-Z\-]`

Comment: In normal POSIX 1003.2 regular expressions a dash is included in a bracket expression by making it the first or last character, or the second endpoint of a range.  Also **most importantly** the '\' character loses all special meaning in a bracket expression!

Comment: @GregA.Woods: A quick look at the docs tells me Go uses Perl syntax, probably by way of the PCRE library.  If this regex is being used in Go as the tags imply, the backslash will *always* be treated as an escape character.

Comment: @GregA.Woods: POSIX standard is irrelevant to the discussion here. Go implements its own syntax anyway.

Comment: Stupid question, but how can a dash be "the last character in a range" if you can't escape anything? I mean, AFAIK a sequence like `A-]` means "A through ]" rather than "A, dash, end of range"

Comment: @MrLister: In POSIX regex, `]` always terminates the character class, unless it is the first in the character class (possibly after negation `^`). You can include `]` inside a collating element `[.].]` to make it a valid end point of a range. Anyway, it is POSIX regex and not related to the subject matter in this question/answer.

Comment: @nhahtdh I hate all these different regex syntaxes. I yearn for the simple days when there was only GREP. Oh, and EGREP.

Comment: Go's native `regexp` package actually uses Russ Cox's RE2 library (I.e. most definitely_not_ PCRE, though it implements a regular expression syntax with features that are _somewhat_ compatible with PCRE).  RE2 also has a POSIX mode (accessable from Go) which is not quite POSIX-compliant.  So, @ireardon, what regular expression package is imported and what compile call is used in the code you're working with?

Comment: BTW, what I meant by referring to POSIX is that in this answer the appearance of the '\' is entirely unnecessary and potentially confusing.

Comment: @MrLister: You are contradicting yourself, since grep and egrep uses POSIX regex.

Answer (score 0):

It excludes the minus sign.

You can test regex handily here: http://www.regexr.com/

Comment: From that page: "RegExr uses your browser's RegExp engine for matching, and its syntax highlighting and documentation reflect the Javascript RegExp standard." So the syntax likely differs from that support by [Go's RE2](https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax).

Comment: @DaveC you're right, but not really in the context of this question IMO. In my experience, basic regex syntax (like OP's `[^0-9a-z-A-Z]`) don't differ much between different engines. For instance, I'd bet that in most browsers, http://regexr.com/3avj4 will give the same result as http://play.golang.org/p/ozmtbUHH7C.

Comment: It doesn't relate to the syntax used in this question, but I just wanted to make it clear that that website (and many others like it) do not exactly match RE2's syntax and in general you cannot cut-n-paste between Go and such a site. I've seen a number of regex questions where apparently the questioner was unaware of syntax differences.